# Building Node.JS on Solaris: "Use of <stdbool.h> is valid only in a c99 compilation environment."

Tags: c, installation, node.js, compiler-errors, solaris

I am attempting to install Node.JS on Solaris. This is out of the box Solaris 9/10 x86 (September 2010 which is most recent) and using only default packages.

The directions I am following are here: https://github.com/joyent/node/wiki/Installation. I am using the latest stable version of Node.JS found on their home page http://nodejs.org

Here is what I have tried...

```
-bash-3.00# export PATH=$PATH:/usr/sfw/bin:/usr/xpg4/bin
-bash-3.00# ./configure --prefix=/tmp/node
Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/sfw/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/sfw/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/xpg4/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : not found 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for program gcc or cc           : /usr/sfw/bin/gcc 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/xpg4/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : not found 
Checking for gcc                         : ok  
Checking for library dl                  : yes 
Checking for openssl                     : yes 
Checking for library util                : not found 
Checking for library rt                  : yes 
Checking for library socket              : yes 
Checking for library nsl                 : yes 
--- libeio ---
Checking for library pthread             : yes 
Checking for function pthread_create     : yes 
Checking for function pthread_atfork     : yes 
Checking for futimes(2)                  : no 
Checking for readahead(2)                : no 
Checking for fdatasync(2)                : no 
Checking for pread(2) and pwrite(2)      : yes 
Checking for sendfile(2)                 : no 
Checking for sync_file_range(2)          : no 
--- libev ---
Checking for header sys/inotify.h        : not found 
Checking for header sys/epoll.h          : not found 
Checking for header port.h               : yes 
Checking for function port_create        : yes 
Checking for header poll.h               : yes 
Checking for function poll               : yes 
Checking for header sys/event.h          : not found 
Checking for header sys/queue.h          : yes 
Checking for function kqueue             : not found 
Checking for header sys/select.h         : yes 
Checking for function select             : yes 
Checking for header sys/eventfd.h        : not found 
Checking for SYS_clock_gettime           : no 
Checking for library rt                  : yes 
Checking for function clock_gettime      : yes 
Checking for function nanosleep          : yes 
Checking for function ceil               : yes 
Checking for fdatasync(2) with c++       : no 
'configure' finished successfully (1.936s)
-bash-3.00# make
Waf: Entering directory `/tmp/node-v0.4.3/build'
DEST_OS: sunos
DEST_CPU: ia32
Parallel Jobs: 1
Product type: program
[ 3/75] cc: deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp.c -> build/default/deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp_1.o
/usr/sfw/bin/gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1 -threads -m32 -g -O3 -DHAVE_OPENSSL=1 -DEV_FORK_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_MULTIPLICITY=0 -DX_STACKSIZE=65536 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DEV_MULTIPLICITY=0 -DHAVE_FDATASYNC=0 -DPLATFORM="sunos" -D__POSIX__=1 -Wno-unused-parameter -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DNDEBUG -Idefault/deps/c-ares -I../deps/c-ares -Idefault/deps/c-ares/sunos-ia32 -I../deps/c-ares/sunos-ia32 ../deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp.c -c -o default/deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp_1.o
In file included from ../deps/c-ares/setup_once.h:73,
                 from ../deps/c-ares/sunos-ia32/ares_setup.h:195,
                 from ../deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp.c:18:
/usr/include/stdbool.h:42:2: #error "Use of <stdbool.h> is valid only in a c99 compilation environment."
Waf: Leaving directory `/tmp/node-v0.4.3/build'
Build failed:  -> task failed (err #1): 
        {task: cc ares_strcasecmp.c -> ares_strcasecmp_1.o}
*** Error code 1
The following command caused the error:
python tools/waf-light --product-type=program build
make: Fatal error: Command failed for target `program'
-bash-3.00#
```

I think the key error is

```
/usr/include/stdbool.h:42:2: #error "Use of <stdbool.h> is valid only in a c99 compilation environment."
```

which I can recreate like this

```
-bash-3.00# cd build
-bash-3.00# /usr/sfw/bin/gcc -D_GNU_SOURCE -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1 -threads -m32 -g -O3 -DHAVE_OPENSSL=1 -DEV_FORK_ENABLE=0 -DEV_EMBED_ENABLE=0 -DEV_MULTIPLICITY=0 -DX_STACKSIZE=65536 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DEV_MULTIPLICITY=0 -DHAVE_FDATASYNC=0 -DPLATFORM="sunos" -D__POSIX__=1 -Wno-unused-parameter -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -DNDEBUG -Idefault/deps/c-ares -I../deps/c-ares -Idefault/deps/c-ares/sunos-ia32 -I../deps/c-ares/sunos-ia32 ../deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp.c -c -o default/deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp_1.o
In file included from ../deps/c-ares/setup_once.h:73,
                 from ../deps/c-ares/sunos-ia32/ares_setup.h:195,
                 from ../deps/c-ares/ares_strcasecmp.c:18:
/usr/include/stdbool.h:42:2: #error "Use of <stdbool.h> is valid only in a c99 compilation environment."
-bash-3.00# cd ..
-bash-3.00#
```

Any ideas? Do I need to specify a different option to use C99 or to not use C99?

Again, this is out of the box Solaris 9/10 on x86. I have not done anything that would change any of the compilers or for that matter any other stuff that is installed by default.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `-std=c99` or `-std=gnu99` to your `CFLAGS` before invoking `./configure`, like so:

`CFLAGS=-std=c99 ./configure --prefix=/tmp/node`

This error means that Node.JS is probably using `AC_PROG_CC` in its `configure.ac` script when it should be using `AC_PROG_CC_C99`, see [the page on C compiler detection on autoconf's manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/autoconf/C-Compiler.html). You should report this bug to the Node.JS developers, and test that the proper solution works on your system.

Comment: `c99` increased the error free life by about one second. But `gnu99` worked for the whole seven minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I got past this error by doing:

CC=/path/to/solaris_32/bin/gcc (and then the make command I was trying to run)

This way it knew to use gcc and not /usr/bin/cc which was throwing the error.

Comment: That's almost certainly because the version of GCC you have installed at `/path/to/solaris_32/bin/gcc` defaults to using C99 or later.

Comment: Sure, latest GCC vs ancient Solaris 10 cc.